# Error when end-users access Contact Dashboard

Tags: contacts, contact-view

I want users to have access to the Contact Dashboard on our CiviCRM site. But I'm currently getting the following error when trying to access. 
[image]
The following permissions I have set.

Authenticated User:

- CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard

Anonymous:

- CiviCRM: profile create
- CiviEvent: register for events
- CiviEvent: view event info
- CiviDonate: make online contributions
- CiviCampaign: sign CiviCRM Petition

If I give the permissions "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API" it fixes the issues but do not probably want to do that.

CiviCRM version 5.22
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any extension that show information on your dashboard?

Comment: No. I have attached a list of extensions. I looking for the end-user dashboard that lists memberships, contributions, etc.

Comment: How about CiviCRM: view my contact permission?

Comment: Yes. I've tried to enable 'CiviCRM: view my contact', 'CiviCRM: profile edit' and 'CiviCRM: profile view' permissions but still get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have this permission (access CiviCRM backend and API) for anyone to access anything CiviCRM related, it's the minimum permission required for anyone to do anything.

You can have a look at some information regarding this here - https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/45

There are a lot of other pages that say similar things as well, it sounds like a scary permission to give someone but in reality it's more of a first step kind of thing.

Unfortunately, this means that anyone with the access CiviCRM backend and API permission can see the CiviCRM menu but there are ways of going about this such as the answers on this question - [How to remove CIviCRM from menu for some roles](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25348/how-to-remove-civicrm-from-menu-for-some-roles)

Comment: Can you pls spell out which 'this' you mean for the permission?

Comment: I would say the "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API" permission

Comment: And now I have the CiviCRM menu showing for my Authenticated Users. Anyone know how to get rid off? Screenshot attached

Comment: @ScottPulver I have amended my answer for you :)

Comment: @Jade I guess I'm a little confused on how hiding that menu will work. I'm trying to use the menu per role module but what menu item do you change in Drupal? I have the CiviCRM links in all the Menus disabled. Not sure if this is an issue because I'm using CiviVolunteer and I can not change the permissions to the menu item in "Navigation Menu" admin settings in CiviCRM. The menu appears on the /civicrm/user when an Authenticated user logs in.

Comment: Thank you Jade for the reply, I had one year ago same problem 
(https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31157/basic-wordpress-user-cannot-see-civicrm) 
but the answers I received were not so clever